# How do I get optimisation in Android without obfuscation using R8

Tags: android, optimization, android-r8

I have some big chunks of code which test the behaviour of some incompletely documented Android APis (sigh) which seem to behave differently for different Android versions and I want to switch them in and out of debug builds (they are always removed from release builds) which I try to do using buildConfigFields in build.gradle like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        buildConfigField("boolean", "RINGERMODETEST", "false")
        ...
    }
    debug {
        // set this to false to remove the optional code
        buildConfigField("boolean", "RINGERMODETEST", "true")
        ...
    }
}
```

Then in my code I have

```
    if (BuildConfig.RINGERMODETEST) {
        // optional code
    }
```

To get the optional code removed I need to turn on the optimiser, but setting minifyEnabled would turn on obfuscation as well which I don't want in a debug build. There is an earlier answer to this question for Proguard at [Proguard shrinking and optimizing without obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438296/proguard-shrinking-and-optimizing-without-obfuscation), but there doesn't seem to be any documentation which says how to do it for R8. I really don't want to have to learn how to construct a complete proguard control file when it's supposed to be superseded by R8. and useProguard will apparently soon be deprecated.

Comment: It looks like similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51860843) and answered [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/bae6ny/r8_and_proguard/).

Comment: The answer referred to by Alex Lipov was to use Proguard, but as I said in my post, Proguard is now deprecated, so that isn't a solution which will continue to work. If R8 is supposed to replace ProGuard, it needs to be as configurable as ProGuard.

Comment: Actually the solution I suggested is for R8. Note that R8 takes proguard configuration files as input, which might be confusing.

Comment: The solution in @AlexLipov's answer doesn't work in R8. It still obfuscates.  Here is a bit of output from my logger `D/Y0() line 845 called from p line 729 called from makeView line 116:` Y0 and p are obfuscated, not the actual method names